# How to get Field Service Dispatcher/Resource license in scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, licenses, field-service-lightning

We need "Field Service Dispatcher", "Field Service Mobile" and "Field Service Scheduling" license in scratch org in order to utilize the FSL managed package.

We have tried to install the FSL managed package in a scratch org, and set up FSL, but we are stopped when trying to create the permission sets for Dispatcher and Resource, as we are missing the Field Service Dispatcher and Resource licenses in the scratch orgs.

Is there any way to include these licenses in scratch orgs, for example through the "features"-property in the project-scratch-def.json file? When you add the feature FieldService you only get the Field Service Standard licens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Salesforce Support, this is working as designed. I'm pushing on them to get this updated so we can have all the licenses we need in a scratch org.

Updated: This is now avablie as of Winter'21. See details here: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_scratch_org_features.htm

Comment: Final response from support is that it is not supported, and there are now plans to support it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue when I select the "Enterprise" edition for my Scratch Org. I can manage to get the licenses when using the "Developer" edition though. So I guess this is a bug

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check it out.